# jQuery function returning undefined, expecting bool

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an issue I am getting bool undefined when I am calling this function which is returning a bool.
It should return me bool value I tried var bool = funcationName() but it is returning undeffiend

IsaAtionResultExist

**createAction**

```
  $("#createAction").click(function() {


    var bools = IsaAtionResultExist(Clinetfirstname, Clinetlastname, datasource, status, cliendid);
                    if (bools === true) {
                    return false;
  }      
});
  }
});
```

**IsaAtionResultExist**
**in Alert it is showing True**

```
   function IsaAtionResultExist(Clinetfirstname, Clinetlastname, datasource, status, cliendid) {
        alert("Second");
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("IsaAtionResultExist", "P4C")',

            data: { Clinetfirstname: Clinetfirstname, Clinetlastname: Clinetlastname, datasource: datasource, status: status, cliendid: cliendid },

            success: function (data) {
                if (data === true) {
                    alert(data);
                    return data;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return data from ajax callback which is not possible.
Javascript is asynchronous so ajax callback returns are not returned by wrapping function.

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax(...)` is an asynchronous call that returns a promise, you can only check for the boolean after the promise has been resolved. I have changed your AJAX function to return that promise, as follows :

```
function IsaAtionResultExist(Clinetfirstname, Clinetlastname, datasource, status, cliendid) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("IsaAtionResultExist", "P4C")',
        data: {
            Clinetfirstname: Clinetfirstname,
            Clinetlastname: Clinetlastname,
            datasource: datasource,
            status: status,
            cliendid: cliendid
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data === true) {
                alert(data);
                return data;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then in your click event, you need to do the following :

```
$("#createAction").click(function() {                     
    IsaAtionResultExist(Clinetfirstname, Clinetlastname, datasource, status, cliendid)
    .done((bools) => {
         // do something with your bools
         // but not a return statement unless you need it for a successive
         // callback chain
    };
});
```